# Extract missing paths from bash array of paths

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have an array of paths:

```sh
paths=(
  /foo/exists1
  /foo/exists2
  /foo/missing1
)
```

To find those that are missing:

```sh
ls "${paths[@]}" 1>/dev/null
```

Shows:

> ls: cannot access '/foo/missing1': No such file or directory

Good. Now I want to clean this up:

```sh
ls "${paths[@]}" 1>/dev/null | sed 's/ls: cannot access //' | sed 's/: No such file or directory//''
```

But I get:

> ls: cannot access '/foo/missing1': No such file or directory
>   /foo/exists1
>   /foo/exists2

So the `sed` doesn't work, and existing files are also shown.

Why does that happen (why does it ignore the `1>/dev/null`), and how do I fix this?

Comment: My interpretation is that you want to remove ("extract") elements from `paths` that don't exist; is that correct? Or, similarly, you want to print only the elements from `paths` that *do* exist?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yeah I'd like to extract missing paths, so I can print them as warnings, e.g. "warning path X does not exist", etc. (Actually, this is a list of paths fed into tar, so I can extract the good paths and use them in tar, and extract the bad paths and log warnings without allowing tar to fail... my solution below works, but I'm not sure it's the best as I've read not to rely on ls, but rather globstars, but it works for now)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Ionix! The word "extract" could be read two different ways ("pull it out and hold it up" or "remove it"), so I wanted to make sure I understood.  I would suggest a slight edit to your question to add the "tar vs log warnings" context, since that helps people give you answers that are more directly usable.

Comment: @womble Funny how I can never get it right on StackExchange. If I'd posted it on SO then someone would have closed it and said to post on SF. When I post on SF someone gets irate and closes it and says to post on SO. On SO I'd say that scripting is "programming thing" and someone would tell me that it's a "sysadmin thing" and go to SF.

Comment: it is tricky to get a feel for a site's scope, unfortunately. I myself didn't realize scripting was off-topic here at SF. For questions like this one, where you're trying to solve a problem in a UNIX/Linux environment, and you're having trouble getting it *just right*, consider the U&L Stack Exchange: unix.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @JeffSchaller LOL Another good option... see what I mean? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've [already discovered](https://serverfault.com/a/1013015/293440) the immediate reason your code didn't do what you expected: errors from `ls` are reported to stderr (as [suggested by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html)), which is not captured as input by the pipe. You therefore got a mixture of normal output (which passed through unchanged by your `sed` statements) and stderr (which bypassed them). I do not know why your `ls` output changed between calls; redirecting stdout to /dev/null should have the effect of removing all "normal" (existing paths) from the output. The fix for this is *not* to shove stderr into stdout, though.

Post-processing the output from `ls` is a dangerous idea if you want a reliable script. One good article on the topic is ["Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), available on the wooledge.org site.  One in-depth Q/A at the Unix & Linux site goes into some of issues: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). The upshot is that UNIX filenames can contain almost any character, including spaces, tabs, newlines, single quotes, double quotes, escaped single quotes, etc! For some quick examples, consider directories by these names, all of which are perfectly legal:

- "No such file" (`mkdir "No such file"`)
- "ls: cannot access 'foo': No such file or directory" (`mkdir "ls: cannot access 'foo': No such file or directory"`)
- "directory

  with

  embedded

  newlines" (`mkdir $'directory\nwith\nembedded\newlines'`)

The first is an innocent directory that is wrongfully captured (from stdout) by the `grep`. The second is also wrongfully captured, but then further mangled into a **completely different path** -- which may or may not exist! -- by the `sed` statements. The third is one example of what happens when you pass the output of `ls` into line-oriented programs; if the directory doesn't exist, `ls` will say so on more than one line, which is probably how you ended up with two separate `sed` statements!

To distinguish "good paths" -- ones that exist and are readable -- from "bad paths", I would suggest looping over the array and building new arrays of each.

```bash
for p in "${paths[@]}"
do
  if [ -r "$p" ]
  then
    goodpaths+=("$p")
  else
    badpaths+=("$p")
  fi
done
```

You can then do whatever you like with each set:

```
printf 'Good path: -->%s<--\n' "${goodpaths[@]}"
echo
printf 'Bad path: -->%s<--\n' "${badpaths[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your way is much safer. My way works but it might break tomorrow when some weird paths get into my "to-backup" list.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be obvious... errors go to file descriptor 2, not stdout.

So must redirect `2` to `1` then grep:

```sh
  paths=(
    /foo/exists1
    /foo/exists2
    /foo/missing1
  )
  ls "${paths[@]}" 2>&1 \
    | grep 'No such file' \
    | sed 's/ls: cannot access '\''//' \
    | sed 's/'\'': No such file or directory//'
```